# If then else ambiguity in CUP

Tags: if-statement, grammar, ambiguous-grammar, cup

I am constructing a grammar in CUP, and I have ran into a roadblock on defining IF-THEN-ELSE statements.

My code looked like this:

```
start with statements;

/* Top level statements */
statements ::= statement | statement SEPARATOR statements ;
statement  ::= if_statement | block | while_statement | declaration | assignment ;
block        ::= START_BLOCK statements END_BLOCK ;

/* Control statements */
if_statement    ::= IF    expression THEN statement
                  | IF    expression THEN statement ELSE statement ;
while_statement ::= WHILE expression THEN statement ;
```

But the CUP tool complained about the ambiguity in the definition of the `if_statement`.

I found [this article](http://goldparser.org/doc/grammars/example-if-then-else.htm) describing how to eliminate the ambiguity without introducing `endif` tokens.

So I tried adapting their solution:

```
start with statements;

statements ::= statement | statement SEPARATOR statements ;

statement  ::= IF expression THEN statement
             | IF expression THEN then_statement ELSE statement 
             | non_if_statement ;

then_statement ::= IF expression THEN then_statement ELSE then_statement
                 | non_if_statement ; 

// The statement vs then_statement is for disambiguation purposes
// Solution taken from http://goldparser.org/doc/grammars/example-if-then-else.htm

non_if_statement ::= START_BLOCK statements END_BLOCK  // code block
                   | WHILE expression statement        // while statement
                   | declaration | assignment ;
```

Sadly CUP is complaining as follows:

```
Warning : *** Reduce/Reduce conflict found in state #57
  between statement ::= non_if_statement (*) 
  and     then_statement ::= non_if_statement (*) 
  under symbols: {ELSE}
  Resolved in favor of the first production.
```

Why is this not working? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the interaction between `if` statements and `while` statements, which you can see if you remove the `while` statement production from `non-if-statement`.

The problem is that the target of a `while` statement can be an `if` statement, and that `while` statement could then be in the `then` clause of another `if` statement:

```
IF expression THEN WHILE expression IF expression THEN statement ELSE ...
```

Now we have a slightly different manifestation of the original problem: the `else` at the end could be part of the nested `if` or the outer `if`.

The solution is to extend the distinction between restricted statements ("then-statements" in the terms of your link) to also include two different kinds of `while` statements:

```
statement  ::= IF expression THEN statement
             | IF expression THEN then_statement ELSE statement 
             | WHILE expression statement
             | non_if_statement ;

then_statement ::= IF expression THEN then_statement ELSE then_statement
                 | WHILE expression then_statement
                 | non_if_statement ; 

non_if_statement ::= START_BLOCK statements END_BLOCK
                   | declaration | assignment ;
```

Of course, if you extend your grammar to include other types of compound statements (such as `for` loops), you will have to do the same thing for each of them.